# Right order of function arguments

Tags: assembly, stack, arguments

i have the following function with three arguments:

```
 sub_602667B proc near 

 arg_0 = dword ptr 4
 arg_4 = dword ptr 8
 arg_8 = dword ptr 0Ch

 push    [esp+arg_8]
 push    [esp+4+arg_4]
 push    15
 push    [esp+0Ch+arg_0]
```

Then I make the following sketch :

```
 esp, ebp -> | Old EBP        |  +0
             | Return Address |  +4
             | Argument 1     |  +8
             | Argument 2     |  +12
             | Argument 3     |  +16
```

And now I have the following on my paper:

```
   push    [esp+arg_8]     => is Argument 2,( because esp + 12(=0Ch) = Argument 2
   push    [esp+4+arg_4]   => is Argument 2,( because esp + 4 + 8 = Argument 2 )
   push    15
   push    [esp+0Ch+arg_0] => is Argument 3,( because esp + 12 + 4 = 16 = Argument 3
```

So my question would be : Is that sketch ok? I wanted to ask because the point that Argument 2 is pushed twice and Argument 1 is not taken surprises me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet does not contain `push esp, ebp`, so why would there be an "old EBP" on the stack? At the beginning of the function, your stack should look like this:

```
esp + 00 | return address
esp + 04 | Argument 1 (arg_0)
esp + 08 | Argument 2 (arg_4)
esp + 0C | Argument 3 (arg_8)
```

After that, remember that `esp` changes after each `push`. IDA is already doing the maths for you and splitting the displacement into the `+4` and `+arg_4` parts — they represent "balance `esp` back to its initial value" and "convert the remaining offset to a local variable", respectively. The function is pushing exactly those variables which are referenced:

```
push    [esp+arg_8]      ; Argument 3
push    [esp+4+arg_4]    ; Argument 2
push    15
push    [esp+0Ch+arg_0]  ; Argument 1
```

---

If you want to find out more, you can highlight the `[esp+4+arg_4]` part in the disassembly and press <kbd>Q</kbd> to convert the displacement to a single number.

Then go to Options > General... > Disassembly and enable the `Display disassembly line parts: [x] Stack pointer` setting.

Now you see the difference between the `esp` value at the start of the function and the `esp` value in the current line.

Subtract that difference from the displacement in the `push`, and you should get the right local variable.